# don't want to refresh & retain last inserted values

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

In my htm page i want to use a button which submit my form by using function. I use validations on my fields and when i press submit button it displays error message but doesnot retain last values it refresh my form. I just want that the values that i entered will be exist there and just the field that has only error message will be disappear. all other fields remain there.
Here is my code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />-->
    <!--
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    -->
    <title>Phone Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/css/view.css" media="all"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/javascript/view.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/javascript/external.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body id="main_body" >
        <img id="top" src="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/images/top.png" alt=""/>
            <div id="form_container">
            <h3>
                <a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/phonereg.php">Phone Registration</a>
                <a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/officerreg.php">Officer Registration</a>
                <a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/customerreg.php">Customer Registration</a>
                <a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/taskentry.php">Task Entry</a>
            </h3>       
            <form  name="order" id="form_532698" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="" >
                <div class="form_description">
                <h2>Phone Registration</h2>
            </div>                      
            <ul >
              <li>
              <span>
                <label class="description">IMEI # : </label>
                <input name="imei" id="imeinum" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="15" value=""/> 

                </span>
              </li>
              <li>
              <span>
                <label class="description" >Phone Number </label>
                <input name="phone" id="phnum" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="11" value="" onblur="validate(this)"/>  

                </span>
              </li>
              <li>
              <span>
                <label class="description" >From Date </label>
                <input id="datepicker" name="fdate" class="element text medium" maxlength="10" value="" type="text"/>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li>
              <span>
                <label class="description" for="element_4">Active </label>
                <input name="r1" id="rad" class="element radio" type="radio" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
                <label class="choice">Yes</label>
                <input name="r1" id="rad" class="element radio" type="radio" value="No" />
                <label class="choice">No</label>
                </span>
              </li>

              <li>
              <input type="button" name="save" value="Save" />
              </li>

              <!--
              <li class="buttons">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="532698" />
                    <input class="button_text" type="submit" name="save" value="Save" id=""  />
                    &nbsp;<input class="button_text" type="reset" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
                    &nbsp;<input class="button_text" type="submit" name="search" value="Search" id="" />
                    &nbsp;<input class="button_text" type="submit" name="up" value="Update" id=""  />
                    &nbsp;<input class="button_text" type="submit" name="del" value="Delete" id="" />
              </li>
              -->
            </ul>
            </form>
    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/track/images/bottom.png" alt=""/>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
//submit form
document.order.submit();
</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Kindly guide me how can i do this?? I'll be thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to prevent form from submiting to server if validation fails:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event){
  if(!isValidForm($(this)){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

supposingly isValidForm() method takes form selector and returns true if form is valid and false if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

use `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;`

Comment: And do you think would it do?

Comment: @VytautasButkus yup if u  use `return false;` it will do it? got any doubt

Comment: @Mona u will get the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the validation is success or not in **$(function())** if not then return false in that.. else return true...

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    if(!validation) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 major ways of doing this: PHP(server-side) and javascript(client-side).

The PHP solution isn't that clean, you need to refresh the page, check the values there and set the correct `value` in every input (removing the ones you want to delete)

The javascript/jQuery solution is cleaner: instead of a `<input type='submit' />` use a button that calls a javascript function, checks every input (if you need server information to check them you can use Ajax) and displays the errors, setting only the ones that were wrong to blank.

Both ways are ok, but the javascript method is much easier to control/update, and it's more user-friendly since it doesn't refresh the page.